# Good, Well, and Better

Tags: grammar

I know the difference between good and well. If we want to say "more good," we use "better." What about if we want to say "more well?"

Example:

> The soup tasted good, but the salad tasted **better**.
>
> The singer performed well, but the dancer performed **[?]**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there are many comparatives and superlatives that are constructed from the adverb or adjective (*fast, faster, fastest*; *clean, cleaner, cleanest*; *high, higher, highest*; etc.) some just need to be learned. In this case, *good* and *well* both employ *better* and *best* as comparative and superlative.

This is just as confusing for English speakers learning languages such as French, where the comparatives and superlatives for *good* and *well* are quite distinct. But what is common is that neither language uses *more good* nor *more well* - both have specific words (*better* and *best*).

To compare the adjective *good* / *bon** and *well* / *bien** we see:

> good - better - best
>
> bon - meilleur - le meilleur

and

> well - better - best
>
> bien - mieux - le mieux

This likely originates from the German roots, where modern German uses *besser* and *beste*.

* and ignoring the gender/plural forms

Answer (score 3):

The comparative "**better**" can apply to both "**good**" and "**well**"